# RHEL: Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'edb'

Tags: rhel, repository

I am on RHEL version 8.3. I am going by the [official instructions](https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-docs/d/edb-postgres-advanced-server/installation-getting-started/installation-guide-for-linux/12/EDB_Postgres_Advanced_Server_Installation_Guide_Linux.1.06.html) here on how to install EnterpriseDB on RHEL.

When I run:

```
sudo dnf -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
```

I get the following error:

```
EnterpriseDB RPMs 8 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                          230  B/s | 381  B     00:01
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'edb':
  - Status code: 401 for https://<username>:<password>@yum.enterprisedb.com/edb/redhat/rhel-8-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 54.165.250.135)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'edb': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

Obviously, `<username>` and `<password>` are replaced with the username and password I'm given by EDB.

I get the same error when I run `dnf upgrade` too.

Is there something wrong with the way I'm doing things? Or is there currently a problem with the EDB repo? and if the latter, how can I check for myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [401 HTTP error code](https://httpstatuses.com/401) means unauthorized client, so the authentication must be failing with the username/password you provided.  Make sure you have it in there correctly, or contact the repo admins.

You can add `enabled=0` to the yum repo file to disable the edb repo, or run `dnf —disablerepo=edb ....` when using dnf.

Comment: The repository password was different from the portal password. I was using the portal password. Thanks @jsbillings.